# GCP API Gateway creation fails with internal server error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openapi, gateway, google-cloud-run

I am trying to automate the api-config and api-gateway creation to expose cloud run service using terraform. Till yesterday it was working well, & api-gateway was serving traffic.
But considering a large volume of requests hitting the API Gateway, I decided to increase the quota for read-requests to a higher number & that's when I modified the openapi swagger file to add in quota for my API.

It worked well for sometime but now when I am triggering my pipeline, it failed with an internal server error. I tried using cloud commands also for creating an API gateway with verbosity set to DEBUG but could not find anything useful.
The api & API config gets created using the openapi file but creation of API Gateway has stopped...with an internal server error.

Attaching my openapi file for reference.:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Offer api
  description: API to get personalized offrs
produces:
- application/json
schemes:
- https
x-google-management:
  metrics:
    # Define a metric for read requests.
    - name: "read-requests"
      displayName: "Read requests"
      valueType: INT64
      metricKind: DELTA
  quota:
    limits:
      # Define the limit or the read-requests metric.
      - name: "read-limit"
        metric: "read-requests"
        unit: "1/min/{project}"
        values:
          STANDARD: 20000
paths:
  /offers: #/{deviceID}/{restaurantID}:
    get:
      description: get personalized offers
      operationId: app.get_offers
      x-google-backend:
        address: ${backend_address}
      parameters:
      - name: deviceID
        in: header
        required: True
        type: string
      - name: storeID
        in: header
        required: True
        type: string
      x-google-quota:
        metricCosts:
          "read-requests": 1
      security:
      - APIKeyHeader: []
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successful Operation
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/APIResponse'
          #headers:
          #   Content-Type:
          #     schema:
          #       type: string
          #   Content-Encoding?:
          #     schema:
          #       type: string
          #  mcd-apiversion:
          #    type: string
          #   mcd-uuid:
          #     schema:
          #       type: string
          #   Cache-Control?:
          #     schema:
          #       type: string
          #   ETag:
          #     schema:
          #       type: string
        400:
          description: Bad Request - Invalid ID Supplied
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/APIErrorResponse'
          # headers:
          #   Content-Type:
          #     schema:
          #       type: string
          #   Content-Encoding?:
          #     schema:
          #       type: string
        # 401:
        #   description: "Not Authorized - API KEY is invalid"
        #   content:
        #     application/json:
        #       schema:
        #         $ref: "#/responses/UnauthorizedError"
        404:
          description: "Resource not available - ID not found"
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/APIErrorResponse'
          # headers:
          #   Content-Type:
          #     type: "string"
          #   Content-Encoding?:
          #     type: "string"
        415:
          description: "Unsupported media Type. Please check the content type in request"
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/APIErrorResponse'
          # headers:
          #   Content-Type:
          #     type: "string"
          #   Content-Encoding?:
          #     type: "string"
        500:
          description: "Internal Server Error. Please refer logs for further details."
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/APIErrorResponse'
          # headers:
          #   Content-Type:
          #     type: "string"
          #   Content-Encoding?:
          #     type: "string"
        503:
          description: "Service is unavailable. Please try after some time"
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/APIErrorResponse'
          # headers:
          #   Content-Type:
          #     type: "string"
          #   Content-Encoding?:
          #     type: "string"
definitions:
  APIResponse:
    type: object
    required:
    - customerID
    - coupon
    properties:
      customerID:
        type: string
        example: "0000"
      coupon:
        type: string
        example: "Christmas100"
  APIErrorResponse:
    type: object
    required:
    - code
    - message
    properties:
      code:
        type: integer
      type:
        type: string
      message:
        type: string
      path:
        type: string
      service:
        type: string
      property:
        type: string
securityDefinitions:
  # This section configures basic authentication with an API key.
  APIKeyHeader:
    type: apiKey
    name: x-api-key   
    in: header
```

**EDIT**
**The issue is resolved. But there seems to be more to it, does anybody has any idea on how to define quota for per day requests? From GCP documentation I am able to find out that we can define per minute requests count.(Read and write) But is there a way to define per day limit on no.of requests for our APIs?**

Comment: The issue is resolved. But there seems to be more to it, does anybody has any idea on how to define quota for per day requests?
From GCP documentation I am able to find out that we can define per minute requests count.(Read and write)

But is there a way to define per day limit on no.of requests for our APIs?

Comment: Could you please explain how you sort your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as the only supported unit for openapi quotas in GCP is `1/min/{project}` as [mentioned here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions#quota)